# bioRxiv - Are previous versions still available to read after revisions?

Tags: arxiv, online-publication, version-control, biorxiv

When a revision of a manuscript is submitted to bioRxiv, is the previous version still available to be viewed? If so, is it possible to hide some of the previous versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When a revision of a manuscript is submitted to bioRxiv, is the previous version still available to be viewed?

Yes. For example, [this](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2023.11.21.567896v1) is the first version of [this manuscript](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2023.11.21.567896v2).

> If so, is it possible to hide some of the previous versions?

I cannot find any option for one of my own manuscript that has versions (but is also somewhat old), don’t remember seeing one, and do not see this option documented. Mind that previous versions are not very prominently displayed in my opinion.

Deleting previous versions would be contrary to the mission/philosophy of BioRxiv to provide a lasting archive of preprints. From [the FAQ](https://www.biorxiv.org/about/FAQ):

> ##### Can I remove a manuscript that has been posted on bioRxiv?
>
> No. Manuscripts posted on bioRxiv receive DOI's and thus are citable and part of the scientific record. […] Consequently, bioRxiv’s policy is that papers cannot be removed. Authors may withdraw their article if they no longer stand by their findings/conclusions or discover fundamental errors in the article. […] In extremely rare cases, papers have been removed because of legal or safety reasons.

In short, deleting manuscripts is only possible under extraordinary circumstances.
While deleting is not the same as hiding, it seems unlikely that BioRxiv would create an option for the latter, as there is no reason to expect that this would be a popular or relevant feature.